# How can I run a Yeoman generated Jasmine specrunner in a grunt server?

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, gruntjs, yeoman

I've learned how to write tests in Jasmine for my Backbone app created with Yeoman. However, I have my test data in a json file. I want to load the JSON using a model fetch but it doesn't work when I just open the file locally because of a bad URI error.

I'm wondering how I can load the generated spec runner in a grunt server so that the request will work?

Another question is when the test actually runs in PhantomJS is it running on localhost or is it just being opened as if opening a file on the file system?

How do you guys normally write your tests? I've been writing some of the test code then running grunt test. If the test fails I open _Specrunner.html in Firefox and inspect. This is pretty tedious and I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really more like three, but I can answer the third. What I've been doing is using [testem](https://github.com/airportyh/testem) which is very useful; just have Chrome visit a URL which is constantly running your tests in the background to make sure that everything's OK. If not, you are notified by the CLI (or the counter in the title bar) to fix the broken code.

My testem.yml config looks like this:

```
framework: jasmine
test_page: lib/testRunner.html
```

And then I persist my specrunner so that I don't have to rebuild a new one every time I want to test something:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test'em</title>
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/testem/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/testem.js"></script>
        <script src="/testem/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/testem/jasmine.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="jasmine_content"></div>
        <script src="vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
        // require config stripped out for brevity
        require(['specs'], function() {
            var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
            jasmineEnv.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter);
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        });


        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I've been using this to test an application written in Backbone using RequireJS and the test runner is pretty robust. I recommend that you give it a go.