# Grunt-contrib-jasmine aborts task when there is no spec file or spec file is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, guard

I have been having great fun getting started with Grunt, but have come across a situation where I don't know what the best course of action is.

**tl;dr**

Can grunt throw a warning without aborting the task? grunt --force will do that, but that applies the force option to all tasks.

**Issue**: on running a task that includes jasmine (from grunt-contrib-jasmine), if it cannot find a spec with at least one unit test in it (i.e. `it("does stuff, function () {});`) then it throws a warning and therefore aborts the whole task.

**Code**

Here is the task I'm using to build up my site:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean', 'sass', 'images', 'favicons', 'lint', 'minify', 'jasmine', 'hashify']);
```

and here is the jasmine task configuration:

```
jasmine: {
        testdev: {
            src: folders.js.src + '/**/*.js',
            options: {
                'specs': folders.spec.src + '/*Spec.js',
                'helpers': folders.spec.src + '/*Helper.js'
            }
        },
        //etc etc, more targets for minified code testing and istanbul coverage
}
```

**Are any of these sensible solutions?**

Option 1) I can use grunt --force but am reluctant to because it will affect other processes that I might want to genuinely fail the task.

Option 2) Warn but don't fail. Does Grunt have a STDOUT warning that doesn't abort the task?

Option 3) I could fork the plugin and add the option 'force' just to the jasmine task so it continues on, but will still log its warning to the console.

Option 4) Grunt creates an empty dummy spec if one is not found before running jasmine.  This seems a bit clunky to me.

There may be an even better solution that I've not yet thought of.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Testem. [I answered this in another unit testing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395579/how-can-i-run-a-yeoman-generated-jasmine-specrunner-in-a-grunt-server/19410590#19410590), but the nice thing about it is it's like a `watch` task for your tests; update your code, it runs, something goes wrong, it logs it on the console (and through the browser that you run it through).

Also, because it uses a browser to run the tests through, you can have a tab next to your project's code which will show a count of the tests that pass/fail. i.e. `Testem (60/60)`

https://github.com/airportyh/testem

If you want to run this as part of your build process as well, [there's grunt-testem](https://github.com/sideroad/grunt-testem). Be careful that you quit the testem runner before running this task or it will fail. Hope this helps. :-)